# How to access static ip windows virtual machine

Tags: windows, azure, ip, virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

While logged into my Windows Server 2016 virtual machine I changed the settings of the Ethernet IP to a static address. Now I am unable to connect to this machine. Any ideas how to reconnect/ reset the IP without being logged into the machine (maybe through the azure portal)?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `reset network configuration` button on the portal.

1. Go to the Azure portal.
2. Select the affected Virtual Machine.
3. Select Network Interfaces.
4. Select the Network Interface associated with your machine
5. Select IP configurations.
6. Select the IP.
7. If the Private IP assignment is not Static, change it to Static.
8. Change the IP address to another IP address that is available in the Subnet.
9. The virtual machine will restart to initialize the new NIC to the system.
10. Try to RDP to your machine. If successful, you can change the Private IP address back to the original if you would like. Otherwise, you can keep it.

reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/reset-network-interface